# Update WPF Slider dynamically based on textbox

Tags: c#, wpf

I am writing a WPF application and I have a slider bound to a textbox and vice versa.

My problem is that when changing the value of the text box, I have to click out of the text box before the value of the slider is updated.

I would like the slider value to change as the user types text into the textbox or when the user presses enter whilst in the text box.

Heres the code I have:

XAML:

```
<Slider Name="sldrConstructionCoreSupplierResin" Minimum="0" Maximum="10" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" IsSnapToTickEnabled="True"/>
    <TextBox Name="txtConstructionCoreSupplierResin" Text="{Binding ElementName=sldrConstructionCoreSupplierResin, Path=Value, Converter={StaticResource RoundingConverter}}" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1"/>
```

Code Behind:

```
public class RoundingConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                double dblValue = (double)value;
                return (int)dblValue;
            }
            return 0;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                int ret = int.Parse(value.ToString());
                return ret;
            }
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, bindings are updated when the control loses focus. That's why you're only seeing the change when you click out of the TextBox. You can change this using the [UpdateSourceTrigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.updatesourcetrigger.aspx) property of Binding, like this:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Value,ElementName=mySlider,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

Now the TextBox will update its source whenever the Text property changes, rather than when it loses focus.

Comment: Thanks for this although I think you need to change it to UpdateSourceTrigger, then since you answered first I'll mark as correct :)

Answer (score 1):

Set the `UpdateSourceTrigger` property of the `Binding` to `PropertyChanged`

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=sldrConstructionCoreSupplierResin, Path=Value, UpdateSourceTrigger = "PropertyChanged" Converter={StaticResource RoundingConverter}}"/>
```

See more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.updatesourcetrigger.aspx)